# Pass a variable into a partial, rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a loop like such:

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
  <% render middle %>
<% end %>
```

Then in my middle partial, how do I access the current post?

Comment: Hello Elliot I'm using this on standard scaffolded. Using inside index.html.erb to render _show.html.erb where show partial contains modal. every thing is working fine except that when I press show link, it is showing same id instead of showing different id's.

Answer (score 236, accepted):

Try this:

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
  <%= render 'middle', :post => post %>
<% end %>
```

Like this you'll have a local variable `post` available within the partial.

Comment: you need <%= %> not <% %> tags or else it will not render

Comment: Keep in mind, you would need `<%= render 'middle', :post => post %>` for rails 3.1.x

Answer (score 124):

Give it to the partial as a local variable

```
<%= render :partial => 'middle', :locals => { :post => post } %>
```

Of course, rails also has a shortcut for rendering collections:

```
<%= render :partial => 'post', :collection => @posts %>
```

In this case it will call the partial post for every post with a local variable 'post'

You can even render a spacer template between each post:

```
<%= render :partial => 'post', :collection => @posts, :spacer_template => 'post_divider' %>
```

Comment: Didn't know about the :spacer_template option, really nice. Thanks!

Comment: Note that the :locals hash is not needed when using Rails 3. The arguments hash is converted into arguments which are passed to the partial.

Comment: I still needed :locals hash for it to work.. I'm running 3.2.12

Comment: `<%= render :partial => 'post', :collection => @posts, as: :post %>`
will automatically loop through each `post` in your partial, so you can use `post` in your partial as the variable.

Answer (score 14):

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
  <% render middle, :post => post %>
<% end %>
```

You can now access post as the local variable `post` in the partial

Answer (score 10):

Replace `<%= render middle %>` with `<%= render middle, :post => post %>`. Then in your `middle` partial, you can access the `post` variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the entire each block with this:

```
<%= render partial: "product", collection: @posts %>
```

Or even shorter:

```
<%= render @posts %>
```

Full documentation (section 3.2)
https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_view_overview.html