# Passing parameters to partial view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a view that displays multiple images and those images' associated tags. I decided to use a partial view for each image and its tags, but I am having trouble passing in the image object into the partial view. Here is the main view's relevant code:

```
<table>
  <% @images.each do |i| %>
    <tr>
      <%= render :partial => :image_tag, :image => i %>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

Here is the partial view's relevant code (partial view is named _image_tag.html.erb):

```
<table>
  <%= image.id %>
  <%= image_tag image.src %>
</table>
```

I read in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4700617/pass-an-variable-into-a-partial-rails-3) thread that I can pass in the image object the way that I am currently doing it. I tried passing in the id through an options hash on the render method, and that also didn't work. The error I am getting is:

```
undefined method `model_name' for Symbol:Class
```

centered around the line where I am calling render :partial in the main view.

Answer (score 114, accepted):

```
<%= render partial: "image_tag", locals: {image: i} %>
```

is how you would pass variables to partials.

Comment: I actually had that already and was getting the exact same error I currently am. Something else causing the problem?

Comment: My guess would be that "image_tag" is a rails helper method and is colliding with your partial name. Have you tried renaming your partial?

Comment: Fair point given the context, but I only put 'image' in the question to keep it simple. My actual code is named differently, so that is not the issue.

Comment: Can you make sure you are in fact passing in the right item, and to make sure that @items is in fact what you think it is?  Do some `puts` statements before rendering your partial to make sure, and some `puts` statements in your partial at the very top.  Can you also try passing the WHOLE `@images` in and check?  This is what I do when I need to figure out what's going on with variables.  Keep us posted! :)

Comment: Well, I figured it out. The problem was that I had the partial's view name as a symbol instead of a string. Once I changed 'render :partial => :image_tag' to 'render :partial => "image_tag"', everything worked out. Not sure why the symbol representation doesn't work, but thanks for the help!

Answer (score 74):

Something else to consider for those that may be having trouble sending value(s) to a partial. **If you omit the 'partial:'** before your partial path, like so...:

```
<%= render 'my_partial', :locals => {:greeting => 'Hello world', :x => 36} %>
```

...it seems you'll be unable to access the locals hash values directly. Rather, you would need to do the following:

```
<div>
  <h1> <%= locals[:greeting] %> , my x value is <%= locals[:x] %> </h1>
</div>
```

However, **including 'partial:'** before your partial path, like the following...:

```
<%= render partial: 'my_partial', :locals => {:greeting => 'Hello world', :x => 36} %>
```

...allows you to directly access the hash values, like so:

```
<div>
  <h1> <%= greeting %> , my x value is <%= x %> </h1>
</div>
```

Just something to consider, I was getting tripped up by this issue when trying to access the locals hash values and realized I had omitted the *'partial:'* component.

Comment: You saved me. Thanks!

Comment: pithier rails 4 syntax  `<%= render partial: 'my_partial', locals: {greeting: 'Hello world', x: 36} %>`

Answer (score 11):

You can also pass the whole object to a partial like this:

```
<%= render :partial => "partialpath", :object => :image %>
```

You would replace i with image in your case and partial path with whatever your partial is called. Inside the partial it would have access to a local variable with the same name as the partials name. So if your partials name is "image" the local variable image will be the object you pass in.

EDIT: Looking at the rails guides looks like in rails 3 the :object is now accessed as an instance variable instead of a local so @image would be what you  use in the partial.

Comment: I don't think your `EDIT:` is correct. [Quoting](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#passing-local-variables): *In previous versions of Rails, the default local variable would look for an instance variable with the same name as the partial in the parent. This behavior was deprecated in 2.3 and has been removed in Rails 3.0.* In your answer, the value of the object passed as `:object` will be accessible inside the partial as a local variable named `partialpath` (not `@partialpath`, `@image` or `image`)