# Rails: get arguments passed to partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

Is it possible to get the arguments passed to a partial from within the that partial?

```
# in some_view.html.haml
= render 'foo_partial', some: "stuff", goes: "here"

# in foo_partial.html.haml
= arguments = ??? # im trying to get this to contain {some: "stuff", goes: "here"}
```

**NOTE** To clarify, I wanted to view all the arguments that were passed to the partial.

**EDIT 2** I'm not asking how to access the variables, but to get a list of everything that was passed in. Mods, please do not change the code provided as it is an example of my situation. Changing code has implications on the question itself.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing parameters to partial view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6672454/passing-parameters-to-partial-view)

Comment: Why was this edited? Changing the example code could potentially change the answer. Come on mods..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I was looking for was `local_assigns`

```
# in some_view.html.haml
render 'foo_partial', some: "stuff", goes: "here"

# in foo_partial.html.haml
= local_assigns # outputs {some: "stuff", goes: "here"}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to pass them as locals

```
render 'foo_partial', locals: {some: "stuff", goes: "here"}
```

You can call them in your view by their key

`some` will return `"stuff"`

Answer (score 0):

You can pass local variables into partials like this :

```
= render partial: 'foo_partial', locals: {some: "stuff", goes: "here"}
```