# Use helpers to clarify code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this sign up form which is quite huge so I'm just showing you a "small" part.

```
<div class="input-element uk-margin-small-bottom uk-flex">
  <% if @user.errors[:first_name].any? %>
    <div class="uk-inline uk-width-1-2" title="<%= @user.errors[:first_name].first %>" uk-tooltip="pos: left">
      <span class="uk-form-icon" uk-icon="icon: user"></span>
      <%= f.text_field :first_name, placeholder: "First name", class: "uk-input uk-form-danger" %>
    </div>
  <% else %>
    <div class="uk-inline uk-width-1-2">
      <span class="uk-form-icon" uk-icon="icon: user"></span>
      <%= f.text_field :first_name, placeholder: "First name", class: "uk-input" %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

This is the logic for **every single input** and the schema is the same:

- Add a tooltip to the section where the field has an error
- Add a CSS class that distinguish fields with and without error

It leads to a huge amount of HTML / Ruby code for the same common mechanism. I know Rails provide some helpers to ease the code in certain scenario.

**Can my issue be resolved with helpers? If it can, how do you reckon I should handle that?**

Thanks,

Comment: you are validating the fields needed in the model?  You should be getting some error showing up, probably easiest to tweak that.

Comment: @RockwellRice Not sure if I've been unclear in my explanations but there is no issue from a code perspective. Everything is working fine and the error messages are displayed correctly. 
My only issue is code readability and I have the feeling to repeat my self between fields. **How could I improve readability with helpers?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say you're probably after a `partial` not a `helper`.

I'd make a partial called eg: `_form_field.html.erb` with contents like:

```
<div class="input-element uk-margin-small-bottom uk-flex">
  <% 
  if model.errors[:field].any?
    title = model.errors[:field].first
    tooltip = 'pos: left'
    input_extra_class = 'uk-form-danger'
  else
    title = '' 
    tooltip = ''
    input_extra_class = ''
  end
  %>
  <div class="uk-inline uk-width-1-2" title="<%= title %>" uk-tooltip="<%= tooltip %>">
    <span class="uk-form-icon" uk-icon="icon: user"></span>
    <%= f.text_field :field, placeholder: label, class: "uk-input <%= input_extra_class %>" %>
  </div>
</div>
```

And then call it like:

```
<%= render 'form_field', model: @users, field: :first_name, label: 'First name' %>
```

Note that in the partial, I've pulled out the bits that do vary into an if-statement, to avoid duplicating the html markup that doesn't vary. That's optional... you can leave it as you had it if you want. But either way, make a partial where you pass in the `model`, `field`, and `label` as local variables.

Here's the rails doco on partials: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials

Comment: Note that you can call this quickly using an array of your fields, for example: `<% [:first_name, :last_name, other_field].each do |field| %>`, and then change the call line to `<%= render 'form_field', model: @users, field: field, label: field.to_s.humanize %>`. And of course `<% end %>` afterwards.

Comment: Thanks, the solution is working. Yet, I've found another way of passing variables through partials (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6672454/passing-parameters-to-partial-view) and it works better in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

I think a partial may be cleaner but you could still use a helper, maybe something like this:

**Helper**

```
def my_text_field(errors, element)
  div_options = { class: "uk-inline uk-width-1-2" }
  input_class = "uk-input"

  if errors.any?
    div_options.merge(title: errors.first, "uk-tooltip": "pos: left")
    input_class << " uk-form-danger"
  end

  content_tag(:div, div_options) do
    content_tag(:span, class: "uk-form-icon", "uk-icon": "icon: user") do
      element.text_field :first_name, placeholder: "First name", class: input_class
    end
  end
end
```

**View**

```
<div class="input-element uk-margin-small-bottom uk-flex">
  <%= my_text_field(@user.errors[:first_name], f) %>
</div>
```