# Passing an instance variable into a form - rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, forms, instance-variables

This is likely an error due to my minimal understanding of Rails and how to use variables across models, so if there is more code needed to answer it or if my terminology is incorrect, let me know and I will gladly update the question.

I have a feed of posts that I want a user to be able to "like." While the following code allows likes to work on an individual post's page - `site.com:3000/posts/*post.id*` - with the form data being passed of `like[liked_post_id]:*post.id*`, when I try to submit a like on a profile - `site.com:3000/users/*user.id*` - which contains a feed of posts, the form data being passed is `like[liked_post_id]:` (blank value)

How can I pass the post's ID within a feed of posts to the `liked_post_id` variable in `_like.html.erb`?

I have noticed that the action of the like form is `/likes` across the board. Would this will only work when you are on the page `site.com:3000/posts/*post.id*`? I'm curious if I need to modify the it so that the action of the form is `/posts/*post.id*/likes` when you are on the page `site.com:3000/users/*user.id*`

From my post view:

```
#views/posts/_post.html.erb:
...
  <%= render 'posts/like_form' if signed_in? %>
...
```

Route to proper form:

```
#views/posts/_like_form.html.erb:
  <div id="like_form">
  <% if current_user.likes_this?(@post) %>
    <%= render "posts/unlike" %>
  <% else %>
    <%= render "posts/like" %>
  <% end %>
  </div>
```

Like from:

```
#views/posts/_like.html.erb
  <%= form_for Like.new, :remote => true do |f| %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :liked_post_id, :value => @post.id %>
    <%= f.submit "Like" %>
  <% end %>
```

From profile (feed of posts):

```
#views/users/show.html.erb
...
  <%= render @posts %>
...
```

Likes controller:

```
#controllers/likes_controller.rb    
  class LikesController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :signed_in_user

  def create
    @post = Post.find(params[:like][:liked_post_id])
    current_user.like!(@post)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to root_url }
      format.js
    end
  end
...
```

User model:

```
#models/user.rb
...
  def like!(post)
    likes.create!(liked_post_id: post.id)
  end
...
```

@frank-blizzard has pointed out that my form markup is an issue. On a post's page the generated markup is:

```
<input id="like_liked_post_id" name="like[liked_post_id]" type="hidden" value="73" />
```

While on the feed page:

```
<input id="like_liked_post_id" name="like[liked_post_id]" type="hidden" />
```

Comment: The creation of _likes_ should be done in controller.

Comment: @Code-Source, see "Edit 1:" above, the _like_ is being created in the like controller.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
<% form_for Like.new, :remote => true do |f| %>
<%= f.hidden_field :post_id, :value => @post.id %>
<%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

The `current_user.likes.build(...)` part should get out of your view and inside your controller. You are using a `current_user.like!` method so I guess you have implemented already some method in user model to accomplish this. If not build your like in the `create` action of LikesController where you can access `params[:like]`.

```
  def create
    @post = Post.find(params[:like][:post_id])
    current_user.likes.build(@post)
    # ...
  end
```

**EDiT**

You might need to pass your @post variable correctly into your _like_form partials, like so:

```
#views/posts/_post.html.erb:
...
<% if signed_in? %>
  <%= render 'posts/like_form', :post => @post %>
<% end %>
...
```

This will give you acceess to a `post` variable inside the partial so you can prepopulate your forms value with its id. See this questions as well [Pass a variable into a partial, rails 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4700617/pass-a-variable-into-a-partial-rails-3) and make sure to read up on how to pass variables correctly to partials. you can debug your views using `<%= debug <variablename> %>`

Comment: Thanks for pointing out some issues I had following Ruby best practice and the location of building the likes. These are topics I'm having a hard time keeping up with while learning rails. I have updated my question with an "Edit 2" to include my like! method.

Unfortunately, I am still only able to submit a like on an individual post's page, while on a profile with a feed of posts, a blank value is sent in the form data for "like[liked_post_id]"

Comment: looks like you are not passing the post variable correctly to your _like_form or _like then. try to inspect the post variable with <%= debug @post %>. Also inspect in your form markup if there is really a value inside your hidden field.

Comment: The form markup is my precise issue. 
On a post's page: `<input id="like_liked_post_id" name="like[liked_post_id]" type="hidden" value="73" />` 
On the feed page: `<input id="like_liked_post_id" name="like[liked_post_id]" type="hidden" />`
Where would I correct the post variable?