# Passing an ID through a hidden form field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I tried to do something similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14802294/passing-an-instance-variable-) in a form, but get this error:

```
Started POST "/opinions" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-01-03 17:11:12 -0800
Processing by OpinionsController#create as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"âœ“", "opinion"=>{"content"=>"This is an opinion"}, "type_of"=>"pro", "topicId"=>"{:value=>2}", "commit"=>"Create Opinion"}
  User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Topic Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "topics".* FROM "topics" WHERE "topics"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", nil], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Completed 404 Not Found in 3ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)



ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Topic with 'id'=):

app/controllers/opinions_controller.rb:6:in `create'
```

opinions_form.html.erb:

```
<%= form_for(opinion, :html=> {class:"form-horizontal", role:"form"}, remote: true) do |f| %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <%= f.text_area :content, rows:4, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Opinion" %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <%= hidden_field_tag 'type_of', typeOf %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag :topicId, :value => @topic.id %>
  <% puts "ID: " + @topic.id.to_s %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <%= f.submit %>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Relevant code in controller:

```
def create
  @opinion = Opinion.new(opinion_params)

  @opinion.user = current_user
  @opinion.topic = Topic.find(params[:opinion][:topicId])
  if @opinion.save
    flash[:success] = 'Opinion Added'
  else
    puts @opinion.errors.full_messages
    flash[:danger] = 'Opinion not Added'
  end
end

private

def opinion_params
  params.require(:opinion).permit(:content, :type_of)
end
```

and finally, relevant code in the topic show page:

```
<td>
  <%= render 'opinions/form', opinion: Opinion.new, typeOf: "pro", :topic => @topic %>
</td>
<td>
  <%= render 'opinions/form', opinion: Opinion.new, typeOf: "con", :topic => @topic %>
</td>
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Although you may be trying to do something similar to that other question, if you have a question then you must include **your** question in your post. Don't make us guess about what you're actually asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see in the request parameters:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"âœ“", "opinion"=>{"content"=>"This is an opinion"}, "type_of"=>"pro", "topicId"=>"{:value=>2}", "commit"=>"Create Opinion"}
```

The `topicId` parameter is not nested under `opinion`, so you need to change your finder to:

```
@opinion.topic = Topic.find(params[:topicId][:value])
```

---

You can also remove the superfluous `value` key in your view:

```
<%= hidden_field_tag :topicId, @topic.id %>
```

Which would further simplify your finder:

```
@opinion.topic = Topic.find(params[:topicId])
```

---

As an aside. Note that idiomatic ruby calls for `snake_case` in all identifiers. This won't change how your code works, but it will help other Ruby developers read your code.