# How to create and use variable in VIews Template in Rails ?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am still new to ruby and rails and is looking to create a variable so I can use it over and over again in the views template. For example,my code right now is

```
<title>Home Page</title>
<h3>Welcome to my Home Page</h3>
```

Now I want to make this "Home Page" as variable or symbol so I can just use that variable/symbol rather than typing the string over and over, how to do it ?

Thanks

Comment: Duplicate of one I just looked up tonight, not even an hour ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4700617/pass-a-variable-into-a-partial-rails-3

Comment: My bad. This is different.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

When I first read your question, I thought you were asking for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4700617/pass-a-variable-into-a-partial-rails-3), but I realize this is different.

Michael Hartl's amazing [Ruby-on-Rails Tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/) demonstrates my favorite method for doing this, which is to create an instance variable that gets referenced in the layout exactly the way you want.

### rails_root/app/controllers/application_controller.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery
  attr_accessor :extra_title
  ...
```

That makes `@extra_title` accessible in all controllers. Now inside one particular controller:

### rails_root/app/controllers/things_controller.rb

```
class ThingsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @extra_title = "| Things"
    ...
```

Ok, so what is this all for? Oh right, we wanted to use this in a layout:

### rails_root/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Best. App. Ever. <%= @extra_title %></title>
...
```

And now you're riding the Rails.

Answer (score 7):

You can use an instance variable `prefixed by @` so that it can be used throughout your view.

For example:

**Controller:**

```
@my_home = "Home Page"
```

**View:**

```
<title><%= @my_home %></title>
```

Comment: What is the advantage of Austins solution when your's is cool short? You should add that my_home has to be in the action of the contr.

Answer (score 1):

In order to do that, you use either a layout or a partial. There is a nice guide here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html

You can put that content in the file app/views/layout/application.html.erb, and it will be used as your default layout.

The other thing you can do, is to create a partial, so you can create a file like /app/views/shared/_header.html.erb with that content, and then you can render it from any view by writting

```
render partial: '/shared/header.html.erb'
```