# Div tag issue in partial form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I've used div id tag, which used to give me drop down in index.html it worked fine, and when I used it in partial form the div part is not working.
I've used JavaScript and Ajax as well.

The code is like this..

`<div title="Show More" class="show_more"></div>`

Comment: Please copy some code here.

Comment: This question is very hard to comprehend. What error are getting exactly? The problem can't be only with this div... please post some more relavant code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the javascript was not being called, so I had to use it again in my partial form and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

If the issue is after adding a partial it is possible your code needs the addition of

```
locals:
```

or

```
collection:
```

See this post for more info on how to [Pass a variable into a partial, rails 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4700617/pass-a-variable-into-a-partial-rails-3)