# passing data to a rails partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Edit: Solution Worked Perfectly.
[dom_id](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/RecordIdentifier.html)

I am trying to pass data to a partial and use it to change roles of a user. Right now it will only change the roles of one user. When it is rendered it only displays and acts on the roles of `User.first`

Where it is rendered. i pass the user in locals. as per [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4700617/pass-a-variable-into-a-partial-rails-3) I used the second answer because the first one didnt work and gave me errors.

```
<%= render :partial => 'roles', :locals =>  { :user => user } %>
```

Below is the partial _role.html.erb

```
<div id="roleModal" class="reveal-modal">
   <%= semantic_form_for user, :url => user_path(user), :html => {:method => :put } do |f| %>
      <h3>Change Role</h3>
      <div class="reveal-modal-body">
         <%= f.input :roles, :as => :check_boxes, :input_html => { :selected => user.role_ids } %>
      </div>
      <a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a> 
      <%= f.action :submit, :as => :button %>
   <% end %>
```

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
<tr>
  <td><%= link_to user.name, user %></td>
  <td><%= user.email %></td>
  <td><%= user.created_at.to_date %></td>
  <td><%= user.roles.first.name.titleize unless user.roles.first.nil? %></td>
  <td>

     <a href="roles#<%= user.id %>" data-reveal-id="roleModal" class="button" type="button">Change role</a>
    <%= render :partial => 'roles', :locals =>  { :user => user } %>

  </td>
</tr>
<% end %>
```

Comment: This does not work although i feel like it should. It only displays and changes the role for the first user. It does not matter who is logged in as long as they are an admin. I am trying to figure out why?

Comment: If you're passing User.first to the partial it's going to render the data for that first user in your database every time.  Call the render partial line in a loop that calls it for each user you want that form to display for

Comment: I do.  I posted the place where the partial gets rendered. It is in a loop of my users. This is in the `index.html.erb` of my users controller. my users controllers index action which provides `@users = User.all`

Comment: Oh ok, without that last edit it wasn't obvious. Seems correct to me as you have it. You could try pasting the code from the partial into your loop in the view and see if it works from there just as a sanity check?

Comment: Yes I recently tried that and got the same result. As an even better sanity check i removed all non erb in the partial. I took out all the divs and everything. Now it renders directly in the table and works properly. It seems that this might have something to do with the foundation 4 reveal modal and how it is called with data-reveal-id. My solution is not clean.

Comment: So your `data-reveal-id` is not unique.  The "Change Role" link is always going to reveal the first occurrence of that ID in the page, thus it's always revealing the form for the first user.  You need to do something like append the `user.id` to the <div> id and the <a> so they're matched up

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You had the original question about passing locals to a partial correct.  The issue was using non-unique pairs of IDs for revealing your hidden forms. So the reveal links always revealed the first occurence of the div with that ID, thus always changing the role on the first user.

Try updating these two lines to use the Rails `dom_id()` helper to create unique matching pairs of `data-reveal-id` to `id` as per the Foundation reveal modal docs:

```
<a href="roles#<%= user.id %>" data-reveal-id="<%= dom_id(user) %>" 
class="button" type="button">Change role</a>

<div id="<%= dom_id(user) %>" class="reveal-modal">
```

Comment: Props good sir. I have been trying to pin that down for 2 days. And you helped me understand a neat helper in Rails that i will spend tomorrow researching. its 3am and on that beautiful note i must sleep. Thankyou Once Again.

Comment: Glad I could help, there's also a `dom_class()` helper to look at as well

Comment: ya i was reading up on them for future reference. Good stuff to know. I dunno if i would have found that because i didnt know what i was searching for.