# Local variable not displaying correctly in foundation's reveal partials

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, zurb-foundation, partials

I have the following code in my view:

```
<% @post_comments.each do |comment| %>

  <%= render partial: "flags/flag_comment", locals: { comment: comment } %>

<% end %>
```

and this in my partial:

```
<div id="flagComment" class="reveal-modal" data-reveal>

    <%= simple_form_for [comment, @flag] do |f| %>

      <%= f.input :reason %>
      <%= f.button :submit %>

    <% end %>

    </div>

<a href="#" data-reveal-id="flagComment" data-reveal>Flag</a>
```

However, the local variable 'comment' is not being set correct.

If i put `<%= comment.id %>` into the partial, I get the same id '9' every time I click the 'Flag' link in my view.

I'm using Zurb's foundation to create the 'reveal', in case that has any bearing.

Could anyone explain what I'm going wrong?

Comment: Do you get the same '9' when you put <%= comment.id %> into the `each` loop above the partial? If so, can we see where your `@post_comments` collection is initialized.

Comment: are you sure @post_comments has more than one value?

Comment: Yes, positive.  '<a href="#" data-reveal-id="flagComment" data-reveal>Flag <%= comment.id %></a>' outputs Flag 9 Flag 5 Flag 4 Flag 3 Flag 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because for all the partials div `id="flagComment"` id is set to the same value.

Data-reveal will look for the div with `id=flagComment` expecting div with an unique id.
If you have multiple div's with the same id, data-reveal will pick the first div with the matching id.
Hence, you get the same id `9`(first div with given id) every time you click on the Flag link.

To resolve this, i would suggest to have different id's for every comment,

For eg : you could do something like this

```
<%= content_tag :div, :id => "flagComment_#{comment.id} ..... %>
...
<% end %>
```

Above will set different id's each time. And you'll have do the same for setting `data-reveal-id` in `a href` tag.

Comment: Thanks, I actually just tracked down this answer which shows how to solve the issue too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15860602/passing-data-to-a-rails-partial