# View Model Form From Within Another Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am working in rails, and I have a application where I want one user to be able to create an instance of another model from their user show page.

I have two tables, one for users and one for cars.
I have the relationships set so one user has_many :cars, and each car belongs_to :user

When the user logs in for the first time, if user.cars = 0 I want the page to display the form to add a car at the users show page.

I was working with Michael Hartl's tutorial which was great, and I tried to use the micropost model work in my situtation but I am getting an error that I can't figure out.

Here is my show.html.erb:

```
    <p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>
<% provide(:title, @user.name) %>
<div class="userwrap">
  <div class="usershow">
    <div class="row">
      <section>
        <h1>
        <%= gravatar_for @user %>
        <%= @user.name %>
        </h1>
      </section>
    </div>
          <p>
            <%= image_tag @user.image.url(:medium) %>
          </p>
          <p>
            <strong>Name:</strong>
            <%= @user.name %>
          </p>

          <p>
            <strong>Email:</strong>
            <%= @user.email %>
          </p>
<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_user_path(@user) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', users_path %>
</div>
  <div class="usercars">
      <%= render 'shared/carform' %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the car form

```
    <%= form_for(@car) do |f| %>
  <% if @car.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@car.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this car from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @car.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :nick %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :nick %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :model %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :model %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :make %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :make %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :neighborhood %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :neighborhood %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :year %><br>
    <%= f.number_field :year %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :picture %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :picture %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Here is my controller show

```
def show
@user = User.find(params[:id])
@cars = @user.cars
end
```

The error I get is

```
First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty
```

I think I have been stumped for too long on this one.  Too deep in the forest to see the trees.  I'm sure it's relatively simple. Should the car controller handle this from within the user view?  If so how do I accomplish that?

Hopefully I was clear.  If you need to see anything else, I'd be glad to post it. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two things I should point out

1. Your @car object is empty, hence it is exactly what it says, First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty, because you are sending @car to a form_for which expects @car to be initialized, which is not initialized in your show action of Users controller.
2. Partials does not have access to instance variables in the controller. Hence even if your @car variable is initialized in the show action of your Users controller, you can't use @car in your partial, instead you need to pass it from render function in your show view page. (See: [Pass a variable into a partial, rails 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4700617/pass-a-variable-into-a-partial-rails-3))

Basically in your controller you need to have something like

```
def show
    stuff here
    @car = Car.new
end
```

Render form should look something like

```
<%= render 'shared/carform', :car => @car %>
```

And you need to create your form like this

```
<%= form_for(car) %>
```

or

```
<%= form_for(@car) %>
```

Depending on where your form gets processed you may or may not need to add additional arguments to your form_for function.

Comment: Is there another way to send it other than form_for?

Comment: Or should I initialize it in my user controller? Which is preferred?

Comment: Also - I have a partial from the Michael Hartl Tutorial that uses @user.errors.any? isn't that an instance variable?

Comment: Yes you should initialize @car in your controller, you also need to pass it as well.

Comment: @Peege151 Either your reading the tutorial wrong, or the tutorial is wrong itself because as far as I know

Comment: When I initialize @car = car within my def show I get unrecognized local variable... gah

Comment: Actually the tutorial is right, but the thing is the partial only has access to @user when you pass it from render, like what I did here

Answer (score 0):

why don't you do redirect the user to edit car page? like the following way:

```
def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @cars = @user.cars
  redirect_to edit_car_path and return if @cars.count == 0
end
```