# Rails form partial that is called via AJAX request is not loading controller variable

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, renderpartial

As the title says, I am trying to load a form partial with an AJAX request; one of the fields in my form requires a variable in the controller so it can create the select dropdown menu. If I render the partial directly in the view, it accesses the variable fine but when I separate the partial and try to load it via an AJAX request, it doesn't know how to find the variable.

I have tried following the answer [found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4700617/pass-a-variable-into-a-partial-rails-3) (giving it to the partial as a local variable) but it still does not work.

**@headers** is the variable that is not being loaded.

**partial**:

```
= simple_form_for(Constraint.new, html: {:multipart => true, autocomplete: "off", :class=> "form-horizontal" }, remote: true, :authenticity_token => true) do |f|
  div.profile-details
    br
    = f.select :header, @headers.each{|header|} , input_html:{:class => "user-update"}, label: "Header", :prompt   => "Select a Header"
    br
    = f.button :submit, "Save Constraint"
```

**.js file that loads partial**:

```
$(".newConditionContainer").append('<%= escape_javascript(render 'projects/rulesConstraintsInput')%>');
```

**UPDATE**:

I ended up defining the variable in the controller method that calls the js request. I had earlier assumed that the variable was accessible but it was only being defined in a method outside of the partial.

Answer (score 0):

Partials need to begin with an underscore so name it something like

`_partial_name.html.erb`

then you can reference a partial using render like this and pass any local variables you like

```
<%= render partial: "partial_name", locals: {headers: @headers} %>
```

Headers will be available as a local varaible inside the partial now. 
Just change @headers to headers

Cheers

Comment: This is the answer I tried and it still doesn't seem to work. My partial is in a separate file if that helps explain it. It just tries looking for the header variable and saying "NoMethodError - undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass".

Comment: How is your .js file getting access to the @headers variable if its stored in your controller?

Comment: That's essentially my question. What would be the best way to access that variable?

Comment: Couple ways I can think of to do it. A hidden input element which you set the value to your headers var and use JS to retrieve it. Or you could use a templating engine like Handlebars.js, you'll be able to generate a section of reusable html and you can just feed it variables from the controller when you render the view.

Comment: Thanks for your help--I ended up just defining said variable in the controller method that calls the js request.